# [cv2.filter2D() on Python]: why does it return these specific values?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, convolution

The following Python script computes the 2D convolution of the blue color channel of a .jpg image:

1. It reads a 6x6 BGR image: [image: image to convolve]
2. It extracts the channel 0. In cv2 this corresponds to color channel blue.
3. I print the values of the channel
4. Input data type is uint8. Therefore, we making cv2.filter2D() and setting ddepth=-1, the output will have data type uint8 too and hence values >255 cannot be represented. Hence, I decided to convert the image from uint8 to, for example, short to have a wider numeric range and be able to represent the values at the output of the filter.
5. I define a kernel of size 3x3 (see the values of the kernel in the code below).
6. I filter the blue channel with the kernel and I obtain a filtered image of the same size due to the padding
7. The filtered values given by the function filter2D() don't correspond to what I would expect. For example, for the top left value the functions returns 449, however I would have expected 425 instead since 71*0+60*0+65*1+69*1+58*3+61*1+89*0+66*0+56*1=425.

Does anyone have any idea about how the filtered image is being calculated by `filter2D()` function? Is there anything wrong with my proposed calculation?

```py
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
    # Read image 6x6x3 (BGR)
    blue_channel=image[:,:,0]
    # Obtain blue channel
    print(blue_channel)
    # Result is:
    #[[71 60 65 71 67 67]
    # [69 58 61 69 69 67]
    # [89 66 56 55 45 37]
    # [65 37 27 32 31 30]
    # [46 23 22 38 43 45]
    # [55 36 44 60 60 47]]
    blue_channel=np.short(blue_channel)
    # Convert image from uint8 to short. Otherwise, output of the filter will have the same   data type as the
    # input when using ddepth=-1 and hence filtered values >255 won't be able to be represented
    print(blue_channel)
    # Result is (same as before, ok...):
    # 71 60 65 71 67 67
    # 69 58 61 69 69 67
    # 89 66 56 55 45 37
    # 65 37 27 32 31 30
    # 46 23 22 38 43 45
    # 55 36 44 60 60 47
    kernel=np.array([ [0, 0, 1], [1, 3, 1], [0, 0, 1] ])
    # Kernel is of size 3x3
    # [0 0 1]
    # [1 3 1]
    # [0 0 1]
    filtered_image = cv2.filter2D(blue_channel, -1, kernel)
    # Blue channel is filtered with the kernel and the result gives:
    # 449 438 464 483 473 473
    # 449 425 436 449 447 451
    # 494 431 390 366 324 301
    # 358 281 243 242 237 240
    # 257 208 219 270 289 312
    # 283 251 304 370 377 347
    print(filtered_image)
    # Why top left filtered value is 449?
    # I would expect this:
    # 71*0+60*0+65*1+69*1+58*3+61*1+89*0+66*0+56*1=425
    # In short, I would expect 425 instead of 449, how is that 449 computed?
```

Comment: code is broken. pay attention when copy-pasting code. take the [tour], review [ask] and [mre]. review the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) while [edit]ing your post.

Comment: I guess it depends on the choice of padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation is not wrong, but you have actually written convolution for value at [2,2], which match with your result 425.

To calculate value e.g. [1,1] you need values outside of the image, you have to handle surrounding edges. And by default in function [filter2D](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga27c049795ce870216ddfb366086b5a04) they are handled as [reflect 101](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga209f2f4869e304c82d07739337eae7c5) , in wiki its shifted mirror [edge handling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Edge_Handling) by +1.

To understand diffrence between mirror(reflect) and reflect 101:

Mirror (reflect)

```
left edge |  image  | right edge
          |         | 
     b  a | a  b  c | c  b
```

Reflect 101

```
left edge |  image  | right edge
          |         | 
     c  b | a  b  c | b  a
```

So calculation for [1,1] with default edge handling in filder2D would be:

```
0*58 + 0*69 + 1*58 + 1*60 + 3*71 + 1*60 + 0*58 + 0*69 + 1*58 = 449
```

Comment: I see that then the key is understanding that the padding is done by filling the edges with Reflect 101. Good point, thank you. 1) Do you know if it's possible that the padding takes place with not with reflect 101 but with for example 0s? 2) When I saw reflect 101, it looked a more complicated technique to perform the padding, is there any benefit of using reflect 101 as padding instead of padding just with 0s?

Comment: ADDED: copyMakeBorder() (see: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-copymakeborder-method/) might be the way to solve padding with zeros using it before filter2D and then throwing away the filtered samples which suffer from the reflect 101 effect.

Comment: @jaj_develop for padding with zeros you can simply call [filter2D(blue_channel, -1, kernel, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/86808/cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT#:~:text=borderType%3Dcv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)) , constant is zero

Comment: When I pass such argument I see that zero padding isn't done in the top, bottom, right and left borders of the image data. Does it work well for you? In any case, I have solved it by first padding with copyMakeBorder and then the padding with reflect 101 from filter2D is thrown away. Thx for your answers! Very useful!